# Configuration for two XBEE S1 together

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am trying to configure two XBEE S1 both of them using the 10EC firmware.

I tried to set this settings on the first one and the second one :

```
ATVR        ATVR
10EC        10EC

ATID        ATID
2001        2001

ATMY        ATMY
1253        1254

ATDH        ATDH
13A200      13A200

ATDL        ATDL
1254        1253

ATA2        ATA2
6           0

ATCE        ATCE
0           1
```

But I still don't have any connections ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution :

You can't have two coordinator in master mode, so one should accept association and be configured as a END DEVICE:

```
ATCE 0
ATA1 6
```

The other one should be set as the coordinator :

```
ATCE 1
ATA2 6
```

After for the addressing you have two solutions :

1. Local addressing using PAN ID (ATID) and Local ADDRESS (ATMY)
2. Global addressing using Source High (ATSH) and Source Low (ATSL)

**For local addressing**

ATID should be the same for both XBEE, ATDH should be set to 0 and ATDL should be set to the other device ATMY:

```
ATID 2001    ATID 2001
OK           OK

ATMY 1253    ATMY 1254
OK           OK

ATDH 0       ATDH 0
OK           OK

ATDL 1254    ATDL 1253
OK           OK

ATWR         ATWR
OK           OK
```

**For global addressing**

ATID should be the same for both XBEE. ATDH and ATDL should be set to the other device ATSH and ATSL values:

```
ATID 1437      ATID 1437
OK             OK

ATSH           ATSH
13A200         13A200

ATSL           ATSL
407E149F       407E15F9

ATDH 0013A200  ATDH 0013A200
OK             OK

ATDL 407E15F9  ATDL 407E149F
OK             OK

ATWR           ATWR
OK             OK
```

Don't forget to save your settings using ATWR

After waiting 10 seconds or using ATCN to close the COMMAND mode, the data you write on one device should be receive by the other one:

```
ATCN           ATCN
OK             OK

Hello World    Hello World
```

To enter command mode you have to wait 1 second enter +++ and wait 1 other second

```
+++OK
```

When you receive OK you can start entering your commands.

It seams that with Xbee Serie 2 you cannot change the local address (ATMY), the PAN Coordinator set it automatically for you. So you should always use global addressing.

Comment: There are just 23 seconds between you posting a question and your own answer. What was the point in asking in the first place?

Comment: The point is that when I wrote the question I find the answer. But I found interresting to let it here as an answer for future people which could have the same problem.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. You can't edit your code, compile, upload, test and write an answer in 23 seconds. :-/

Comment: @Natim, maybe a more substantial answer would be useful here.

Comment: @Kortuk is it better like that ?

Comment: @Natim, Yes, it seems much improved.

Comment: @stevenvh - It's OK (and actually encouraged) to post questions to which you already know the answer.  Both the question and answer should meet our ordinary quality guidelines, and in this case, (after the edits), they do.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463 for more information.

Comment: @Kevin - [not everybody seems to agree](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/posting-questions-including-answers).

Comment: @stevenvh: Then they should read the FAQ

Comment: @endolith - reading the FAQ doesn't imply that you agree with it. They posted their personal opinions.

Comment: @stevenvh: Then their opinions are wrong. :D

Comment: @Natim Don't forget that if your answer to your own question solves the problem, you should select it as accepted answer.

Comment: @AndrejaKo you are right but since we have to wait for 2 days, I forgot to mark it as resolved.